# Ceiling fan and light work with pull chain only, not light switch

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan and light will only work with the chain and not the switch. When I tested the wires with the switch off one still came back hot. My house is a very old house. A picture is posted, as I’m so lost on what to do. Please help!!! [image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeA3U.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeA3U.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxmFn.jpg)[image]

Comment: Has it always been like this or is this a new problem?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box in question please?

Comment: The old fan that was in there seemed to work fine, but when I hooked the new one up it hasn’t worked.

Comment: Can you get rid of that electrical tape and include a clearer picture?  Is there a stamp on the ceiling box that says it's rated for a ceiling fan?

Comment: No there’s not, but the ceiling fan worked fine last time? I’ll post a picture without the tape.

Comment: @Franklin2324 -- in your photo of the ceiling box, which wire rang hot with the switch off?

Comment: @JACK with that ancient wiring you're expecting there to be a fan rated box? I agree is _should_ be, but I wouldn't expect to find it...

Comment: I added more images above. The far right wire is the wire that remains hot.

Comment: @FreeMan  I don't know when they started stamping boxes rated for ceiling fans but the fans have been used for at least a century. I've seen many installed in old boxes with double nuts on the box brackets... I guess it's just an old habit to have a DIYer check the box. :-)

Comment: And it's a very good idea to check for a fan-rated box, @JACK. I _personally_ wouldn't expect to find one in conjunction with such old wiring, but it could be.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a switch loop so you need to take your always hot black wire and connect it to the white wire with the black markings (can you read the markings). Put some black tape on that white wire to show it's always hot. Hook your fan up to the remaining two wires. Put some black tape on the white wire at the switch box too. Leave the ground from the fan unhooked since you don't have  ground there.

Now for the bad news. I doubt that that ceiling box it rated for a ceiling fan and it needs to be changed out. While the box could be firmly mounted to the joists, the threads and screws you use to attach the fan to the box are not strong enough. If you have attic access, changing out the box won't be too bad but if you don't, You might have to remove some of the ceiling to replace the box.

Comment: Okay, so I should hook the black and blue wire to the other black wire and the white wire to the old white wire, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will try that!